# About metrizability of weak topology on $\mathcal{M}(\Omega)$ the space of all finite borel measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

> Is the weak$^*$ topology on space of all finite Borel measures defined on a compact set metrizable?

Is this true for any bounded domain instead of compact set?
I know a result from [Kesavan](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Functional_Analysis.html?id=DCFNPgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) that

> A Banach space $X$ is separable if and only if the weak$^*$ topology on the closed unit ball in $X^*$ is metrizable

In order to use this result I need $\textbf{Space of all finite Borel measures defined on a compact set}$ is separable. Is this true? $\textbf{OR}$ Is there any other way to prove this?
Any references is greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: @KyleGannon But I know that Space of all bounded variations is not separable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space . can you give me some references

Comment: If $\Omega$ has uncountable subset $S$, then you can consider Dirac delta measure $\{\delta_s: s\in S\}\subset M(\Omega)$. Now note that $\Vert\delta_s-\delta_t\Vert=2$ for $s\neq t$ and recall that $S$ is uncountable, so $M(\Omega)$ is not separable. Thus in many cases $M(\Omega)$ is not separable.

Comment: @Norbert Then are Dirac measures dense in $\mathcal{M}(\Omega)$? I don't know how to prove/disprove it.

Comment: Nevermind, I missed that you are talking about weak* topology.

Comment: Sorry if I miss anything but as far as I understand you need separately of the space of continuous function on $\Omega $, not separately of the space of Borel measures

Comment: @Bananach oh! yes, here I need only separability of $C(\Omega)$ in order to prove metrizability of weak$^*$ topology of $\mathcal{M}(\Omega)$, which I have. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Bananach Could you some references? I mean now I want to know whether $\mathcal{M}(\Omega)$ is separable?

Comment: What do you mean? I just informed you that you misread your own reference

Answer (score 3):

The dual of an infinite dimensional normed space is NEVER metrizable in its weak$^*$ topology (otherwise it would be a Frechet space and the closed graph theorem then implies that the weak$^*$ topology coincides with the topology of the dual norm which onyl holds in finite dimension).

Comment: but there is a result: If X is separable then its dual $X^*$ is metrizable

Comment: No! If $X$ is separable then *the unit ball* of $X^*$ is metrizable in the weak$^*$ topology.

Comment: please give me some examples!!

Comment: I don't understand what kind of example you are looking for. Perhaps: If $\Omega$ is a compact metric space then ${\scr M}(\Omega)$ is weak$^*$ metrizable if and only if $\Omega$ is finite.